# How to put darkness to an image?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a masthead component where the proper background should be like this

[image]

but right now it looks like this

[image]

And this is how I am attaching that image

```
<div class="bg_image"
     style="background-image: url('images/driver_rewards/masthead_desktop.jpg')"></div>
```

css

```
.bg_image{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 503px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't darken the image in an image editor? One option would be to overlay an element over your image and make it translucent via `opacity`

Comment: You can apply an overlay on top of the background using a pseudo element which you can apply opacity on.

Comment: does the background-image style need to be inline, or can you move it to the CSS `.bg_image`?

Comment: Refer to the [CSS opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) and find the title : "Text in Transparent Box" you can get an idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [filter](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) and set the brightness:

```
.bg_image{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 503px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Comment: I am using scss. Isn't necessary the webkit thing right?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer  supposed you use an autoprefixer, no it's not

Comment: Thanks bro! It works perfect.

Comment: You're welcome. @NietzscheProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an overlay on top of the background using a *pseudo element* which you can apply `opacity` on.

```css
.bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent url(//lorempixel.com/300/200) no-repeat 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.bg > * {
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.bg.darken::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h2>Without pseudo element for darkening</h2>
</div>
<div class="bg darken">
  <h2>With pseudo element for darkening</h2>
</div>
```